# multiple template parameter lists are not allowed with only one template parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2013, function-templates

Say I have the following struct:

```cpp
struct something{
    int data;
};
```

Now say I want to create a template function that performs some operation with arrays and returns this struct.

```cpp
template <typename type>
struct something func(type* arr, int size){
    //do something
    return {0};
}
```

However, returning `int` from the function:

```cpp
template <typename type>
int func(type* arr, int size){
    //do something
    return 0;
}
```

Doing the following fails and gets me the following error:

```
error C3857: 'something': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed
```

as you can see in the following picture:
[image]

Or giving the struct a `typedef`'ed name instead:

```cpp
typedef struct something{
    int data;
} SOME_NAME;

template <typename type>
SOME_NAME func(type* arr, int size){
    //do something
    return {0};
}
```

Both compile perfectly.

Help me understand this weird issue.

Comment: Drop the `struct` from `struct something func(type* arr, int size)`. Also, when it's possible, do provide a [mcve].

Comment: please do not paraphrase the error, instead post the code and the matching complete error message. I have no clue how you can get an error along the line of "multiple template parameter lists are not allowed" from that code. Maybe you do from different code, details matter.

Comment: C++ does not require you to prefix references to struct types with `struct`, like C does. And you don't need the `typedef`, either. In any case, `return 0;` does not work when the return type is a `struct`. In your example, `return {0};` would work, since the struct's 1st data member is an `int`.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number
I am using visual studio MSC version 180021005, And that is the entire code I am using that causing this error.. I made a new project in visual studio, wrote this code and tried to compile

Comment: Don't use `return {0};` when the return type is `int`, use `return 0;` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau I only used it as an example (the real code tries to return a struct) but you are right, I changed to code to match your suggestion but the error still occurs.

Comment: @PaulSanders I am using visual studio MSC version 180021005

Comment: @Adam [can't reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/clQx8lrmsevUBOuC)

Comment: "multiple template parameter lists are not allowed" is not an error message. Maybe its part of an error message. There seems to be an issue with msvc @godbolt currently, so I cannot see for myself, gcc and clang produce nothing like that. Please include the complete error message in the quesiton. At the bare minimum it should tell you the line number where the error occurs

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I provided the full line and a screenshot for the error that occurs

Comment: Looks like error #1 is the most relevant message. But since #3 makes a backward reference to the earlier declaration and the messages are sorted by line number, it shows up at the top of the list. (MSVC is still wrong, but at least this makes a bit more sense.)

Comment: @aschepler could you explain what the problem is then? even line 1 makes no sense to me since I attached the entire code and I don't know why it thinks it is a class template

Comment: `template <typename type> struct something` looks like you're about to define a class template. But when followed by `(` and not by `{` or `:`, it should realize the `struct something` is just the long way of typing `something` as a function return type.

Comment: @aschepler oh.. is the compiler really goes by that? shouldn't it parse better? people said they could not reproduce this problem. is it possible this problem won't happen in different compilers? is there a way to "fix" this problem in visual studio msvc?

Comment: @Adam According to your tag, whether you are using the visual studio 2013? If so, I suggest you could try to use visual studio 2019. I couldn't reproduce the issue in the Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: i dont know visual studio, but I believe it has a tab that lets you see the actual compiler output, because the Error list is what the IDE made from the compilers output and sometimes it rather obfuscates the error message than making it more clear